# Facebook JS SDK graph call returning error in internet explorer 9-11

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a site that uses the FB SDK to log in the user and make a FB graph call to get their info. The issue is that it doesn't work in IE9, 10, or 11 - but it works in Chrome and Firefox. The code is as follows:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId: '{ AppId }',
    xfbml: true,
    cookie: true
  });
</script>
```

To initialize the SDK. Then we have a client side library that has the following functions to get the user's facebook information.

```
window.rest = {

getUserFbInfo: function(fn){
  rest.checkLoginStatus(function(){
    FB.api('/me', function(userData){
      console.log('userData', JSON.stringify(userData))
      fn(userData);
    });
  });
},

checkLoginStatus: function(fn){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(res){
    if (res.status === 'connected'){
      fn();
    } else {
      FB.login(function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(res){
          if (res.status === 'connected'){ fn(); }
          else { return; }
        });
      }, { scope:'email,user_birthday,user_location,publish_actions,user_likes' });
    }
  });
}

};
```

The problem is in the first function. The output I get from the console log (stringified to make it easier to debug in IE) is this:

```
userData {"error":{"type": "http", "message": "unknown error"}}
```

Not shown, but a console log of the response from FB.getLoginStatus returns that the user is connected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone cares about this issue, IE needs P3P headers to be set on the server.